# Underscore issues: Jekyll + redcarpet == Github flavored markdown?

Tags: github, markdown, jekyll, github-pages, redcarpet

I'm buliding  a site with github pages and do *not* want underscores within words to italicize portions of those words.  E.g.  `function_name_here` should not render with *`name`* italicized.  I understand github flavored markdown is supposed to be smart like this; but I'm still seeing italics in my rendered page.

I have set in my `_config.yml`

```
markdown: redcarpet
```

... anything else I need to do to get Github flavored markdown behavior?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The version of Jekyll available on github's gh-pages does not run the latest version of redcarpet (redcarpet2) which supports these features.  [There's a plugin to provide the latest version of redcarpet to Jekyll](https://github.com/nono/Jekyll-plugins), in which you can then configure to the behaviour you want, i.e. then add this to your `_config.yml`

```
markdown: redcarpet2
redcarpet:
  extensions: ["no_intra_emphasis", "fenced_code_blocks", "autolink", "tables",     "with_toc_data"]
```

Yes, I agree it seems crazy that github doesn't run the same markdown parser on gh-pages as it uses for its github-flavored-markdown everywhere else on the site.

Comment: As of Jekyll 0.12.0, redcarpet2 is supported by Jekyll without the need for a plugin, so the approach shown in the original question should now work without additional modification.

Comment: According to the [GitHub pages Jeklly docs](https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-with-pages) they are now using redcarpet 2.2.2.